Open app in Terminal. How can I pin its icon to the doc?
I just installed Parsehub on a System 76 Lemur Pro running Pop!_OS 22.04. Question applies to other apps though When I run Parsehub via the command line, the app's icon appears on the dock. How can I save it so it stays there even when the app is closed? When I right click on the icon, there is no option to save it to favorites. Thank you!

Not sure if there is another way, but I would do a .desktop entry :)

That did it, thanks @Bog!

Well a .dekstop entry should do the job. Here is a nice guide on how to do them:

Guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Desktop_entries
List of Keys: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys

An Example of a .desktop entry, but I would recommend you to edit it for your needs:
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=ParseHub
Path=/opt/
Exec=ParseHub
Comment=A free and powerful web scraping tool
Icon=[Optional; You have to download the Logo and insert the Path]
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;Office;Utility


That did the trick, thank you!
